# what is the easiest way to put multiple separate videos one after another in Blender

Tags: video-editor, blender

I'm currently using Blender on Ubuntu for video editing. It's not that easy to drag videos and put it close to another, one by one when there are many separate videos. Is there any easy method to do this other than dragging each and every one of these?

Consider number of videos like this:

[image: many videos in a grid]

Comment: Welcome Dscript :) Please check if this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28450/drag-and-drop-multiple-files-in-the-vse solves your issue and keep me posted. Anyway, enjoy video.se!